# How do I compress video in Sveltekit using @ffmpeg/ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, sveltekit

I am trying to compress video in Sveltekit using @ffmpeg/ffmpeg after npm install @ffmpeg/ffmpeg @ffmpeg/core. Here is my code below in the folder /src/lib/compress.Dolo.js

```js
// @ts-ignore
import fs from 'fs';
// @ts-ignore
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
// @ts-ignore
export async function dolo(inputfile) {
    try {
        await ffmpeg.load();
        ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'test.avi', await fetchFile(inputfile));
        await ffmpeg.run('ffmpeg -i', 'test.avi', 'test.mp4');
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./test.mp4', ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'test.mp4'));
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

After uploading a video file to my +page.server.ts as shown below

```js
import {dolo} from '$lib/compress/Dolo'
import fs from 'fs';
import ffmpeg  from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

handleSubmit: async ( event: { request: { formData: () => any; }; }) => {
    const data = await event.request.formData();
    const fileu = data.get('file-input') as File;
    const abuffer = await fileu.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(abuffer));
    dolo(buffer);
}
```

when i run the code, it gives and error in my console as shown below:

```
[info] load ffmpeg-core
[info] loading ffmpeg-core
TypeError: fetch failed
    at fetch (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\index.js:105:13) {
  cause: Error: unknown scheme
      at makeNetworkError (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\response.js:351:9)
      at schemeFetch (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:893:14)
      at C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:602:22
      at mainFetch (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:652:7)
      at fetching (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:517:3)
      at fetch (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:245:16)
      at fetch (C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\undici\index.js:103:20)
      at C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\@ffmpeg\core\dist\ffmpeg-core.js:215:32
      at C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\@ffmpeg\core\dist\ffmpeg-core.js:215:254
      at C:\Users\Boteng\Botengsveltekit\node_modules\@ffmpeg\core\dist\ffmpeg-core.js:215:277 {
    [cause]: undefined
  }
}
```

Please Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: (Please format code [properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) next time.)

Comment: Thanks H.B for helping and pointing that out